# How to change the icon of the exe file of a Console Application base on the value in the App.config file?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, console-application

I have this on my App.config in my console app.

```
<appSettings>
   <!-- Value can either be Logo1 or Logo2 -->
   <add key="Logo" value="Logo1" />
</appSettings>
```

How do I change the icon of the exe file in the bin folder of my project, based on the value of the Logo?

Comment: So the logo will appear during run-time? or change the icon in the Explorer window itself?

Comment: let me know if it is not duplicate

Comment: @Sunil the latter. If possible

Comment: I think you can't set it in Settings... The exe icon is set at compile time and configured inside`*.csproj` file.

Comment: Ok. That makes a lot of sense.  Thanks

Comment: It is not possible.  The OS assumes that the lowest number icon stored in the unmanaged resources of the executable is the desired icon.  Modifying those resources on-the-fly is not an option, they are hard-baked in the file when you build it.  Even modifying it and rebuilding the app often fails, the OS also stores the icon in a cache so it doesn't have to dig it up repeatedly.